# Not able to add new claim in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying add new claim in wso2 .,The claim name is "**Tenant**".

however we are not able to add the claim ,getting below error

> error while adding claim mapping. duplicate claim exist in the system.
>   please pick a different claim uri

*version wso2is-5.1.0.*

**Note** : We are able to add in another claim name like "**Tenant1**".

please refer the screen [Addining new claim screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdRSH.png)   [Addining new claim screen 2-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z7Wk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding claims to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" dialect, please go to List Claims and check whether you already have this claim listed under that dialect.

Comment: Thanks. let me check and update .   where  we can find XML file for "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity". I was looking entries "claim-config.XML" and not found any entries.

Comment: It is in the management console. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+Claim+Mapping

Comment: Thanks for your response.